# MS Access shows American and British Date formats

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have created an MS Access application where requests are recorded and once approved, a Date/Time column is populated. However, I noticed some dates are recorded as American and European format dates, i.e. For January 2, 2018, some records appear as 01/02/2018 and some are 02/01/2018.

I have a backend database and distibuted the frontend to 700+ users.

Is there anyway I can correct this?

Comment: What is your desired date format?

Comment: Fix the column so it is defined as `date` rather than a string.

Comment: The column is Date/Time. I would prefer the European format. In my VBA SQL, I am updating the [Approved On] column as "...[Approved On] =#" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:hh:ss AM/PM") & "#...

Comment: What date is 11/10/2018 - Nov 10 or Oct 11?

Comment: The thing is it appears as both. Since I have distributed it already to 700+ users, I lately realized that their system date/time format may be set as either American or European. I want to set someting in the frontend that limits all date/time entries to European format.

Comment: Just today, a number of requests were approved. Some show as 02/06/2018 and some show as 06/02/2018. It's kinda frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am updating the [Approved On] column as
>   `[Approved On] =#" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:hh:ss AM/PM") & "#"`

This was a very bad idea. When writing date/time to the database, don't format as string, just use the date/time output of functions or other date/time fields.

```
UPDATE foo SET [Approved On] = Now()
```

works just fine.

I'm afraid you are in a world of pain now, since some of the dates have actually been saved wrong in the database (switched day/month). Good luck fixing the existing data.